# Add new lines on CSV file

Tags: bash, csv

I want to transform a CSV file using bash by adding new lines into it depending on some conditions described below :

CSV file structure:

```
name,id_name,url
Amy,N1,http://google.com
Rob,N2,http://google.com http://other-url.com http://anotherurl.com http://other-again.com
Johh,N3,http://google.com http://anotherurl.com
Jack,N4,http://google.com http://other-url.com
...
```

I want to transform the CSV file like this :

```
name,id_name,url
Amy,N1,http://google.com
Rob,N2,http://google.com
Rob,N2,http://other-url.com
Rob,N2,http://anotherurl.com 
Johh,N3,http://google.com
Johh,N3,http://anotherurl.com
Jack,N4,http://google.com 
Jack,N4,http://other-url.com
...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of splitting the last field and then printing the 1st and 2nd field followed by the set of these slices:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{n=split($NF,a," "); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1,$2,a[i]}' file
```

Which returns:

```
Amy,N1,http://google.com
Rob,N2,http://google.com
Rob,N2,http://other-url.com
Rob,N2,http://anotherurl.com
Rob,N2,http://other-again.com
Johh,N3,http://google.com
Johh,N3,http://anotherurl.com
Jack,N4,http://google.com
Jack,N4,http://other-url.com
```

Answer (score 1):

This awk should work:

```
awk -F '[, ]' -v OFS=, '{for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) print $1, $2, $i}' file
name,id_name,url
Amy,N1,http://google.com
Rob,N2,http://google.com
Rob,N2,http://other-url.com
Rob,N2,http://anotherurl.com
Rob,N2,http://other-again.com
Johh,N3,http://google.com
Johh,N3,http://anotherurl.com
Jack,N4,http://google.com
Jack,N4,http://other-url.com
```

- `-F '[, ]'` sets field separator as comma or space.
- Then just start iterating from field #3 and print it along with first 2 fields.

Answer (score 0):

with bash

```bash
while IFS=, read name id url; do
  set -f
  for u in $url; do
    echo "$name,$id,$u"
  done
  set +f
done < file
```

```
name,id_name,url
Amy,N1,http://google.com
Rob,N2,http://google.com
Rob,N2,http://other-url.com
Rob,N2,http://anotherurl.com
Rob,N2,http://other-again.com
Johh,N3,http://google.com
Johh,N3,http://anotherurl.com
Jack,N4,http://google.com
Jack,N4,http://other-url.com
```

This will not pring any records for which the url field is empty.

I'm taking advantage of shell [word-splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) with the unquoted variable in the for-loop. For safety, I'm turning off [filename expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) while I do that.

Answer (score 0):

`perl -F'[, ]' -lane 'for ($i=2; $i<=$#F; $i++) {print "$F[0],$F[1],$F[$i]"}' file`

`-a` autosplits each line into the `@F` array
`-F'[, ]'` autosplit field separator is either a comma or a space
`$#F` is the index of the last element of the `@F` array
perl arrays start with index `0`, while awk starts with `1`